# How to create an universal usable exe file for Windows Vista or higher?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, exe

After developing a simple application with Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5, I would like to create an exectuable (`.exe`) file which is usable for all modern Windows platforms (Windows Vista or higher).

**Question:** All I have to do is to ensure that the target platform (Windows Vista or higher) installed .NET 4.5 and hand out the executable (`.exe`) file, which Visual Studio puts in the `bin\Release` directory? Am I missing something?

Comment: not just the executable but any associated dlls as well

Comment: Any dependencies that your application has, as @daveL said - DLL's, custom files, DB's etc... as for the application itself, why not create an installer using InstallShield LE which will do it all for you, download the pre-requisites and so on?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas thank you, I will have a look at InstallShield LE. The usage of InstallShield LE is not for free, is it?

Comment: I honestly cannot remember. It is a replacement from the Visual Studio installer package that used to be in VS2010 and earlier. There maybe certain elements free but not others

Comment: You might also look into ClickOnce which is baked into Visual Studio and will take care of including your .dll dependencies and installing .NET on machines that don't have it. It will also lets you easily deploy updates to your app.